# In TradingView, why when we "pause" an alert, it dispears?

Tags: tradingview-api

When you click on "stop" (see image below), the alert disappears, but I would like to keep my alerts on the side then activate them when I want. Is it not possible ?

[image]

Regards

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: @Alejandro if you read the tradingview-api tag comment, you will see that this question totally fits

Comment: From the tag except: `Do not use this tag for questions about the website` and `Use this tag for questions related to the programming API of TradingView products`. This is entirely about using a widget in the website and nothing about programming. If so, the usual "post the relevant code along with errors, problems and expected results" applies, though. Otherwise, my close-vote remains.